# VSCode automatically formats console.log() output in terminal when logging an array that is longer than 5 elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to log out an array in the terminal but it automatically formats it and adds a new line if the array is longer than 5 elements. How do I make it print normally in a single line.

Example code:

```
const someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
console.log(someArray)
```

Result:
[Result of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTKzW.png)

Comment: It is not typescript or vscode, it is node that formats the output

Answer (score 0):

It can be annoying sometimes, this is my solution to fix it when I need to print something line by line.

```
const someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
// The last parameter 4 is for indentation.
console.log(JSON.stringify(someArray, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your purpose.

```
const someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
console.log(someArray.join(", "));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple use JSON.stringify(array);

example :

```js
const array = [2,3,2,23,3,3,5,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,4,2];
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```